# vue - how to use a local styling library with css and js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

i want to use a local style library from my company.
It includes a css file for styling and a js file for events like open tooltips, etc.
I included the css file with `import local_style from "./styles/local_style.css";` in my main.js.
That works fine.
But how to I use the js file? I included the file like the above one but it doesn't work.
If I use it in a pure html site and include both files normally, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The js file should have some export/exports.
You should `import * from 'jSfile'` in your main js or import each individual export that you need to use in each component.
Then you should register it as `import {individualExportName} from 'jsFile'` and use it in your script as eg:`individualExportName.functionName()`